# WooCommerce reset product variations list to first one after using browser back button and page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a problem with WooCommerce variations dropdown list. When user refresh the page, list is reseted too. But when the user add product to cart, then page is reloading but list is not reseted to default (first, empty) option.

I was trying to trigger
`<a class="reset_variations" href="#">` on page load with JS but still after reload selected variation is the one that user selected.

Here is my JS:

```
(function($){   
     $(function() {
        $(".reset_variations").trigger("click");
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Same problem exists ehen user use browser back button. Also can't reset the list to the first, empty option from SELECT list.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Hi @Mike did you fix this issue? If yes could you help me to get this fixed? I have the same problem. Thank you :)